# Order of an element and non trivial subgroups of a group

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am currently looking at number theory and I am stuck on how exactly you work out orders of an element and non-trivial subgroups.

Given a group, say $G=\Bbb Z_{73}^×$, I understand that working out the order of a group is where $\operatorname{ord}(G)=|G|$. But, I've come across questions where they ask about specific elements and don't know how I will go about answering it, say for example compute the order of 13 in $G$.

Also when it comes to subgroups, I'm slightly confused, because this group $G$ stores only non-zero integers that are invertible, I read on some definitions that a subgroup has to include the identity, but in this kind of group zero is not part of the subgroup. I've also read that trivial groups are the identity and $G$ itself. What I find hard is that I don't understand the requirements of a regular subgroup from a Group that doesn't include 0.

Any information would be helpful!

Comment: For a group under operation of multiplication, what is the identity? Consider the positive real numbers as an example.

Comment: Moreover, what exactly is the question here?

Comment: @user328442 the main questions I need answering are as follows:  how would I work out a question like 'Compute the order of element 13 in G?' and how to work out non trivial subgroups of G.

Comment: What do you mean by “work out non trivial subgroups of $G$”?

Comment: any group is able to have at least 2 subgroups by default, which are known as the trivial subgroups. These are when the subgroup is equal to the identity element or G itself. These are the Trivial subgroups, any apart from these two are non-trivial.

Comment: To rephrase what I mean: are you asking how one determines whether or not a subset of the group is a non-trivial subgroup?

Comment: @user328442 thanks for all your information so far, really helpful! and to answer your question, I more so need to understand how you go about working out a subgroup, but focusing on non-trivial ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the element $0$ is not a member of the group.

Let $G$ be a group. The criteria required for a subset $H$ of $G$ to be a subgroup is that $H$ must be a group under the same binary operation as $G$. That is, $H$ must contain the same identity element as $G$, the product of any two elements in $H$ must be contained in $H$, the inverse of any element of $H$ must be contained in $H$ and the binary operation within $H$ must be associative.

Usually, to see whether or not a subset of a group is a subgroup, we need only verify that closure under the binary operation holds within the subset and that the inverse of any element of the subset is also contained within the subset.

I don’t know what notation you are using to represent this group but I’ll use the notation from Galian’s “Contemporary Abstract Algebra”.

We will define the group $U(n)$ as elements the integers from $\{1, 2, \cdots, n\}$ that are relatively prime to $n$ with the operation being multiplication modulo $n$. The identity element is $1$ and the order of an element $x$ is the smallest natural number $m$ that satisfies

$$x^m = 1 \text{ mod}(n).$$

For example, consider $U(10)$. The elements of $U(10)$ are $\{1, 3, 7, 9\}$. The identity here is $1$ and the order of $3$ is $4$, the order of $7$ is $4$ and the order of $9$ is $2$. Moreover, a non-trivial subgroup of $U(10)$ is $\{1, 9\}$.

To go along with what you have, consider $U(73)$. The identity is $1$ (as opposed to $0$, which is the identity when the operation is addition) and the order of $13$ is the smallest $m$ that satisfies

$$13^m = 1 \text{mod} (73).$$

I don’t know how much group you know but a corollary to a famous result is that the order of an element divides the order of a group. In this case, the order of $U(73)$ is $72$ (since $73$ is prime) and so we would only have to check to see which divisor of $72$ that $m$ will be.

In this case, it turns out that the smallest $m$ that will work is $72$ and so the order of $13$ in $U(73)$ is $72$.